# Is it possible to find an element according to "p" tag but click "a" tag those are inside "div"?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I'd like to select some schemas on the screen for testing. But there are 8 different types schemas. And I couldn't select any schema without click on the schema's image. The element is displayed like this;

I created web element list and filtered it on value that i wanted to select schema name with java 8 stream than i can replace filtered element with (up div[class=' up template-list-board row']>div>P to div[class='template-list-board row']>div>a) , but it was not a good idea, i've experienced.
So , is there any way to click that "a" tag?

The html is displayed like this;

```
<div class="template-list-board row">
    <div class="template-item-list">
        <a class="item-image-click" ....> </a>
        <p class="item-name">Meeting Agenda</p>
    </div>
    <div class="template-item-list">
      ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I am understanding you correctly, but my solution would be something like this (with XPATH not css):

1) create a string for the locator:

```
String locator = "//div[class='template-list-board row']//p[text()='" + hereYourNameVariableAsString + "']/preceding-sibling::a";
```

2) Then create your element :

```
WebElement element = driver.findELement(by.xpath(locator));
```

Here the important thing is that you locator is dynamic you will have to provide you menu name or whatever that name represent such as "Meeting Agenda". Then it will find that menu and the previous sbling `a` for clicking. I hope I understand the problem correctly and this helps.

Comment: I am glad you did. How did you solve it? Is it easier than what I have above.

Comment: Hello, i created a custom method for the page 1- Create 2 web element lists on css (list1->".template-item-list>p" , list2->".template-item-list>a) 2-Use stream for java for filtrering list1 to find an index number (because a and p tags has same index numbers for the related fields in my case) 3-Use the index number for list2 than click on it